# Rendering Just one module/state of Angular app

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I've angular app with lots of `states and modules etc`. Now, I want to send a link to the user. When user'll hit this `url`, I want to redirect him to a new tab rendering only that particular state (specified in URL) i-e I don't want anything else to be visible to the user. Or you can say, I want to open a `popup window` rendering that particular state's html in popup window . This is the approach that comes to my mind to sort it out.

Ps. There are Rest APIs at the backend which I am calling through angular `resource` service to bind data with the `model` of the views

**Option**

I've rest APIs on backend, So, I was thinking to developing s separate `Nodejs` application, And I will send `nodejs` application url to the user and in the `default/home route` I'll call backend API and, the returned resultset will be rendered in `html` file within nodeJs application and this way, I'll render the corresponding data to user's browser window.

This is the flow for that[image]

I don't know if that is right or clever approach. Please suggest me what will be the best approach to sort it out.

Thanks in advance.

This is what my app looks like

[image]

Everything in the left `side-nav` is a `module` and clicking on this I am routing to a different `state`. I am using `angular-material` and lots of other dependencies in this project.

And this is what I want.

I'll refer a link to the user for example `www.myapp.com/specificpage.html`. And hitting this `url`, a new `tab/popup` will be opened rendering state defined in the same app but with some `non-editable url`. And it should like.

[image]

Comment: When you say `I don't want anything else to be visible to the user.` means do you have other state links in your page? can you please attach the screenshot for the page so I can have a better idea?

Comment: yeah. let me attach it

Comment: @varit05. I've edited the question. Let me know if you still need to discuss anything

Comment: 1. Can you prevent access to the app for the unauthenticated user? The user needs to login in order to access the other routes. 2. not to include the nav module to the app when someone is redirecting from another website. not sure if it helps you.

Comment: Yes. User always needs authentication to access the app. But other modules are used for different purposes. Would it be Ok, if I don't include anyother module when redirected from other sites ? Would this be an efficient approach ?

Comment: you can create a state at a root level with a url and redirect the user to that state and show whatever you want. Or override all parent templates with blanks or custom templates and show the user whatever state you want? 

http://mywebsite.com/#/some/state/1/here
--user clicks a link, opens new tab goes to --
http://mywebsite.com/#/somerootstate/1. Also you can just open a new state in a modal?  Or a modal with white background (covering the things at the back)?

Comment: @Axr, I though about it. I even tried this kind of solution but some of my fellows told me that this won't be the right/clever approach. Anyways, I think I'll have to go for the approach I mentioned in my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve this and each approach has advantage and disadvantage. You have to choose depending on requirement and architecture. Details are below-

1. **Create a separate app** - You can do it through separate code base or use the module based build process and include this module only for new app.
2. **Divide application is two part, public pages and private pages** - Include this page and required APIs for this page in the public modules for your app.
3. **Send token in the link** - If you want to make secure page, send short lived token in the eMail and validate token on the server before displaying page to the user.

Comment: Thanks for your response @ManishSingh. I've decided to create a separate app for this purpose.